# Is this query possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my table:

```
table employee (
    char(50) name
    datetime startdate
    datetime finishdate
}
```

Assume that at least one employee started everyday since the start of the business so that

```
 select distinct startdate from employee
```

would return every day the business was open. I've already provided a query to get every day the business was open, but would it be pair each day with the number of employees that were employed on that day? Essentially I am asking whether it is possible to count the number of employees for which (startdate <= day AND finishdate >= day) is true for each day and return that relation in one query.

Comment: try the query and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.startDate, COUNT(e.startDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT startDate FROM employee) AS x
    INNER JOIN employee AS e
        ON x.startDate BETWEEN e.startDate AND e.finishDate
GROUP BY x.startDate
```

Comment: +1 for not assuming exactly one employee started on each date

Comment: Well done sir. I has something similar, but forgot about group by. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e1.startdate, COUNT(*) AS num_employed_on_date
FROM employee e1 INNER JOIN employee e2 
  ON e1.startdate BETWEEN e2.startdate and e2.finishdate
GROUP BY e1.startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

'startdate' holds the date an employee joined the company.

If you get MIN for startdate and MAX for finishdate, you'll have the entire span of time the company was open.

What you suggested would return every date at least one employee joined the company / started working.